# Copying a number from one workbook to another and then coverting that number to a % format is adding two extra places

Tags: excel, formatting

For example, I copy these 4 items from workbook 1 to workbook 2.

73.05
73.78
70.66
66.75

and then after pasting them and changing the formatting to percent, it turns into:
7305%
7378%
7066%
6675%

That's not what I want. I want :
73.05%
73.78%
70.66%
66.75%

Answer (score 0):

Formatting as percent multiplicitets the value automatically by 100, because '%' means per hundred '/100', so if you want the values to look the same, you must divide them by 100.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to avoid the additional of the formula for /100. I appreciate the answer!